# How to refresh a form with various modals?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, sign, allow-modals

I'm looking for making a signup form with modals, the plan is when somebody enters the site web, there write her or his name and a password, after with a function get the data with ajax, and insert the dates in the DB but my question here is after that what I should do for put to the user the next modal with the next questions?

Comment: I'm working with bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ajax is send, prepare html at server side and send html In response. Once you get html append it in div and then close existing modal and show newly added modal which come on ajax response and appended on div